# How to downgrade ubuntu to python 3.6?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, pip

I'm trying to install an older version of tensorflow and it needs python3.6 to support the whl file of installation.
I'm now running Ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.8.5, I've already done this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

followed by :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

By doing that it installs python 3.6 but when I see the version of python installed it's still 3.8.5. Should I do something to remove python3.8.5 ? maybe apt-get purge ?

P.S: I'm installing the wheel file through pip3 should I downgrade it too ?

Comment: Have you considered using virtual environments or something similar?

Comment: "Should I do something to remove python3.8.5 ? maybe apt-get purge ? " you absolutely should not touch the distro's bundled 3.8. Distros actively use the scripting languages they bundle, and it's very much possible ubuntu has routine scripts coded specifically for Python 3.8 (3.7 added useful stdlib modules and 3.8 added multiple syntactic features)

Comment: `pip3.6 install tensorflow`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't hack the system installation of Python I'd say.
Instead you should use something that let's you manage multiple versions of it, something like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

It is a well-known and widely accepted utility and according to its readme:

> pyenv lets you easily switch between multiple versions of Python. It's simple, unobtrusive, and follows the UNIX tradition of single-purpose tools that do one thing well.

You can find the installation instructions here: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout.

Once you installed it you can install your preferred Python distribution which will live besides your system one and all the others you want later.

E.g. if you want to install 3.6.7 and then use it globally you can do:

```
pyenv install 3.6.7

pyenv global 3.6.7
```

Then test it like:

```
python -V
```

And that's only to scratch the surface, you can do many more things with it, check out the documentation for more.

Comment: If they already installed `python3.6` this is just an unnecessary detour. They should simply figure out where the package installed `python3.6`. (Hint: `/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.6.list`)

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem, I've just introduced the one I use and prefer. Also I'd find it more convenient and easier to manage all my python distros with one tool, rather than having remember what was installed where.

Answer (score 1):

after the commands you've run, you should have a `python3.6` binary installed on the path

that said, I'd recommend using virtualenvs instead of system installations

for deadsnakes, you can install the `venv` module by (`sudo`) `apt install python3.6-venv` (debian decided to split `venv` into a separate module, so the deadsnakes packaging follows that)

from there you can create and activate a virtualenv:

```sh
python3.6 -m venv venv  # create the environment
. venv/bin/activate     # activate the environment
pip install ...         # install things to your isolated environment
```

inside this virtualenv the `python` command will refer to your own isolated python installation

---

disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of deadsnakes